# Queries inside foreach how to

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

This might be weird to ask since is a very straight forward situation, but for some reason is not working

I have an array for testing so here is my "array"

```
$getData =
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [duck] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [duck] => 6
        )
)
```

So then I have a foreach as follow...

```
foreach ($getData as $k => $v) {
$duck = $v['duck'];

$cn = conection();
$query = "select * from table where duck ='$duck'";
$doit = $cn->query($query);
$row = $doit->fetch_assoc();

if ($row['duck'] == $duck) {
echo "We got a duck!";
} else {
echo "We don't have a duck";
}
}
```

so the idea is that I have 2 keys with sub-keys with values... if I'm just to hecho each value as I please I have no problem I get, 3, and 6, but the query only get executed once, so it only checks the first value from the array and the second value is ignored.. why?..

The whole idea is that in this case... if DUCK exist in the table then just update that column if DUCK doesn't exist then Insert the DUCK... but the problem is that the query only get executed once, even with 6 main keys in the foreach... here is ony 2 keys 0 and 1 .. so the query should get executed 2 times thus the IF statement should check every time the query get executed but instead it sent me straight to the ELSE like the value doesn't exist or is not equal when in fact duck do exist...

Thank you for taking the time.

---

ok, it seems that I made a mistake by trying to hurry up I did raw code as an example... so here is My actual code... Joomla 2.5.X

```
foreach ($getData as $k => $v) {
            $duck = $v['duck'];
            $d = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $d->getQuery(true);
            $query
                ->select($d->quoteName(array('duck')))
                ->from($d->quoteName('#__ducks_items'))
                 ->where($d->quoteName('duck') . ' = ' .$duck);
            $d->setQuery($query);
            $ress = $d->loadResult();
            // print_r($k);
            // print_r($ress);
            if($ress == $sku) {
                echo 'We have a duck: ' . $duck ;
            } else {
            echo 'A new duck has born: ' . $sku ;

}

                print_r($getData);
            }
```

hope this help....

Thank you.

Comment: If that's your exact code it should be throwing a parse error. Take a look at the syntax highlighting near the bottom (`'We don't have a duck'`) You need to escape the `'`

Comment: You really shouldn't open and close your connection with each itteration

Comment: no, is not the actual code, and thanks for noticing that... just a typo and you can see i have many... I just want to represent the whole idea..

Comment: not to mention that he's using `$rows = $doit->fetch_assoc();`  but then later references it as `if ($row['duck']`

Comment: Also you don't need to actually fetch the data, you can just count the results (if you're using MySQLi use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows))

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the data as

```
$rows = $doit->fetch_assoc();
```

and using $row inside the if condition.

```
if ($row['duck'] == $duck)
```

should be

```
if ($rows['duck'] == $duck)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is `$rows` not a `$row`

```
    if ($rows['duck'] == $duck) {
        echo 'We got a duck!';
    } else {
        echo "We don't have a duck";
                  ^^^^^
    }
```